# Python for loop repeats

Tags: python, mysql

```
    def get_user_data(self,start_url):
        html = requests.get(url=start_url,headers=self.headers,cookies=self.cookies).content
        selector = etree.fromstring(html,etree.HTMLParser(encoding='utf-8'))
        contents = selector.xpath('//span[@class="ctt"]/text()')
        times = selector.xpath('//span[@class="ct"]/text()')
        data = {}
        for each_text in contents:

            data['content'] = each_text.encode().decode('utf-8').replace('\u200b','')

        for each_time in times:
            month_day, time, device = each_time.split(maxsplit=2)
            data['mobile_phone'] = device
            data['create_time'] = month_day + time
            data['crawl_time'] = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
            self.mysql.insert(data)
```

I want to insert data into the database，But the data['content'] field is repeated，How should I modify it?

Comment: If I understand what you mean, and probably I don't, your `each_time` loop should be inside the `each_text` one

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll get to know the usage of the zip function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should iterate through `contents` and `times` in parallel, instead of one after another. Try using `zip`.

```
def get_user_data(self,start_url):
    html = requests.get(url=start_url,headers=self.headers,cookies=self.cookies).content
    selector = etree.fromstring(html,etree.HTMLParser(encoding='utf-8'))
    contents = selector.xpath('//span[@class="ctt"]/text()')
    times = selector.xpath('//span[@class="ct"]/text()')
    for each_text, each_time in zip(contents, times):
        data = {}
        data['content'] = each_text.encode().decode('utf-8').replace('\u200b','')
        month_day, time, device = each_time.split(maxsplit=2)
        data['mobile_phone'] = device
        data['create_time'] = month_day + time
        data['crawl_time'] = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        self.mysql.insert(data)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll get to know the usage of the zip function